# Apache Nifi - Getting unique records from CSV files

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have two csv files and both files have records. I want to delete duplicate records. I want to get unique records. How can I do it with Apache Nifi?

Thank you !

**input1.csv** ;

```
id,surname,name
1,ali,veli
2,mert,tolga
```

**input2.csv** ;

```
id,surname,name
1,ali,veli
3,ahmet,ozan
```

**output.csv** ;

```
id,surname,name
1,ali,veli
2,mert,ayşe
3,ahmet,ozan
```

Comment: No bro, Duplicate recordings are also coming in that answer. I don't want duplicate records. output.csv file must have unique records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing Record based processing and combine the MergeRecord to merge the two csv files into one and then you can use QueryRecord processor for deduplication with query like:

```
SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE
```

SELECT DISTINCT FROM FLOWFILE will not work. Here are Calcite docs https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html

So you would need:

- CsvReader controller with ignore header set to true.
- CsvRecordWriter controller
- MergeRecord
- QueryRecord

on the output on the QueryRecord you will get deduplicated CSV file.

[image]

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, it is worked!